# Trying to keep the last li item of navbar to rightmost corner. Float :right wont work as expected. How can I fix this?

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

This is my code(something like this). Trying to keep last li at right corner. But float wont work as expected. Help appreciated.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
        <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li  class="nav-item dropdown" >
                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="test"  data-toggle="dropdown">test </a>
              </li>
             <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="float:right">
                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="test"  data-toggle="dropdown">test </a>
              </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to go about it, but it will also depend on whether you have:

- Multiple `<ul />`s
- Single `<ul />` with only 2 dropdowns
- Single `<ul />` with multiple dropdowns

#### Multiple `<ul />`s

If you can change its layout, you can break up the dropdowns into 2 `.navbar-nav`, and set `justify-content` as `space-between` on `.navbar-collapse` so that the right `.navbar-nav` will be pushed to the right, since `.navbar-collapse` has already been displayed as flex-box:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button />
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-lg-between">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" />
                <div class="dropdown-menu" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" />
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/62sf4kvr/19/

Documentation for Bootstrap flex-box built-in classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/

#### Single `<ul />` with only 2 dropdowns

If you can't change the layout and have to go with a single `<ul />` approach, and you only have 2 dropdowns, you can apply the same concept on `.navbar-nav` instead of `.navbar-collapse`: to set `justify-content: between;`. The only additional thing you would need to do is to set the width of `.navbar-nav` to 100%.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button />
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-lg-between">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" />
                <div class="dropdown-menu" />
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" />
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/62sf4kvr/23/

#### Single `<ul />` with multiple dropdowns

If you have multiple dropdowns but only want to put the last one to the right, while the rest will align to the left, the above approaches won't work because they use `justify-content: between;` for the effects.

In order to do that with multiple dropdowns, you can set the margin left of the last dropdown to auto, which will push itself to the furthest to the right:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button />
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav w-100">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" />
                <div class="dropdown-menu" />
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" />
                <div class="dropdown-menu" />
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-lg-auto">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" />
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/62sf4kvr/26/

Comment: I am generating this list through backend so i have to do it without splitting in two ul. Is there a way we can do it in single ul ?

Comment: @testguest: please see my updates. I hope those includes all the cases you have and answer your question.

Comment: Thank you soo much. Was really struggling with this one . Really appreciate your help.